# Unhighlight first highlighted item from AutoComplete

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here I am using `p:autoComplete` tag in  PrimeFaces 5.1, but I can't remove first highlighted/selected item from the suggestions list. How I can remove this ?

Comment: there is no any attribute found that we can configure this issue. I also tried solution from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4551)

Comment: In that case, it's not selected it's highlighted you mean ?

Comment: Like standard google search work, is it possible in this case ?

Comment: See the answer which does the same!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your "problem" comes from this particular [`line`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js#L469),

```
firstItem.addClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

What happens here is when the suggestions are ready to show up the script highlights the first item of the list, so in your case you would just "unhighlight" that item.

I have created a small function that would do that on every AutoComplete you have, you can call it in your `document.ready` or where ever you see suitable:

```
function removeHighlightedFirstItem() {
  var oldAutoCompleteShowSuggestions = PrimeFaces.widget.AutoComplete.prototype.showSuggestions;

  PrimeFaces.widget.AutoComplete.prototype.showSuggestions = function(query) {     
     //calling original ShowSuggestions 
     oldAutoCompleteShowSuggestions.apply(this, [query]);
     //after ShowSuggestions
     //remove first item highlight 
     var firstItem = this.items.eq(0);
     firstItem.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
  }
}
```

The result would look like this:

[image: end-result]

**Note**: The feature you are requesting is available for 5.1.5, 5.0.14 and 5.2 by adding the `autoHighlight = "false"` attribute to the component.

Comment: How submit form on press enter key, currently I have to press ESC in auto-complete before press enter key, and then it submit form on press Enter ?