# Submitting form by hitting ENTER event in primefaces p:autoComplete

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Below is my code:

```
<h:form>   
  <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteID" value="#{myBean.item}"  
                       completeMethod="#{myBean.completeMethod}"    
  </p:autoComplete>
  <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.searchRelatedItems}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here my scenario is like standard Google search, I can see related Items in suggestion and also redirect another page based on text typed in p:autoComplete text field. Its works fine by click on Button, but I also want to achieve by hitting ENTER in p:autoComplete text field.

Comment: I am facing same problem, please help me out....

Comment: I've already seen the exact same question on SO and without an aswer as well... one workaround that doesn't work fully is to add "<p:defaultCommand target="yourSubmitButtonId" />" to the form. If you press ESC to hide the autocomplete selection overlay you can then press enter to submit the form. This still is an issue though...

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but I will just leave it here...

- Try using a Primefaces commandButton, it is p:commandButton, not h:commandButton.
- Make sure the attribute type of the commandButton is "submit" and not "button", "submit" is the default in Primefaces.
- Lastly a certain (but nasty I believe) solution is to put an id at the commandButton like "search-button" and an id at the h:form like "searchForm" and put the following at the p:autoComplete or h:form `onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 13) {  document.getElementById('searchForm:search-button').click(); return false; }"`

Similar topic: [Submit form with primefaces widgets on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963879/submit-form-with-primefaces-widgets-on-enter)