# Submit form with primefaces widgets on enter

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to have my `primefaces` `p:commandLink` submit a `h:form` when the user presses the `enter` key.

I tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form) and in a couple of other places. I also tried the `primefaces` `defaultCommand`. No matter what I try, the browser seems to notice the button press, but the `action` is not performed.

These are my form's widgets:

```
<p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{home.searchKeywords}" completeMethod="#{home.completeText}" style="" />
<p:commandLink id="srchbutton" action="#{home.goToSearchResults}" onclick=" $('.prgrs').show();">
    <h:graphicImage id="srch" name="images/searchbutton.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:-0px;"  />
</p:commandLink>
<p:defaultCommand target="srchbutton" />
```

Comment: Define 'no luck',  be way more explicit what does not work and debug so you get to the why

Comment: No luck means that the form is not submitted. The browser seems to notice the button press, but the action is not performed. I'm also editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: No, onclick is not fired.

Comment: Not submitted is still to vague. See e.g. the question by QueryLars. That is debugging

Comment: I answered QueryLars's question. Like I said, it seems that the browser notices the 'enter' being pressed, but the action, namely 'home.goToSearchResults' isn't performed.

Comment: You answered it most likely at the same time I was responding. Then remove the onclick and see if it makes a difference. Is the action called when you do a real click? Check network traffic, try different browsers etc…  All kinds of things you can try and debug yourself.

Comment: Yes, the action is performed when I do a real click. Removing the onclick doesn't solve it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h:form onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {  document.getElementById('form:srchbutton').click(); return false; }">`

Make sure your real id of link is "form:srchbutton" or put whatever it is.
You can use developer tools or firebug to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

Dijana's solution is right, but the action `onkeyup` should be used and not `onkeypress`.

ENTER is an action event so it will not be caught by onkeypress which captures basic and meta characters. 
So you need onkeydown (which can cause problems if ENTER is down even after the next page loads) or onkeyup.